# What is wrong in the following angularjs code

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

What is wrong in my code? it is not working properly

My .html page looks like
I am a beginner level coder and have below codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Index</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("in script");
        var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
        app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope , $http) {
            refreshData();

            function refreshData(){
                alert("function called");
                $http({
                    alert("get all countries");
                    method: 'GET',
                    url:'http://localhost:8081/SpringWithAngularJs/rest/countries.json'
                        }).success(function(data)
                            {

                            $scope.posts = data;

                            });
            }
            $scope.form = {
                    countryName : "pp",
                    population : "1000"
                        };
            $scope.add=function(){
                $http({
                    alert("add countries");
                    method: 'POST',
                    url:'http://localhost:8081/SpringWithAngularJs/rest/countries/create/'+$scope.form.countryName+'/'+$scope.form.population
                    }).success(function(data){
                        alert("Country Added");
                        refreshData();
                        });
                }
            $scope.remove=function(data){
                $http({
                    alert("delete countries");
                    method: 'DELETE',
                    url:'http://localhost:8081/SpringWithAngularJs/rest/countries/delete/'+data
                    }).success(function(data){
                        alert('Country Deleted');
                        refreshData();
                        });
            }
        });
        </script>
        </head>
    <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>Country List</h1>
        <table border="">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Country Id</th>
                    <th>Country Name</th>
                    <th>Country Population</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tr ng-repeat="c in posts">
                <td>{{c.countryId}}</td>
                <td>{{c.countryName}}</td>
                <td>{{c.population}}</td>
                <td><button ng-click="remove{$index}">Remove</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <h1>Add Country</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Country Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="form.countryName"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Country Population:</td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="form.population"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><button type="submit" ng-click="add()">Add</button></td>
            </tr>

        </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

my controller looks like:
When running the html page not even alert functions of javascript is working.
why this is happening?

```
package com.cg.springwithangularjs.controllers;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.cg.springwithangularjs.dtos.Country;
import com.cg.springwithangularjs.exceptions.CountryException;
import com.cg.springwithangularjs.services.CountryService;

@RestController
public class CountryFrontController {
    @Autowired
    CountryService countryService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/countries",method=RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
    public List<Country> getallCountries(Model model){
        System.out.println("in function");
        try {
            return countryService.getAllCountries();
        } catch (CountryException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/countries/create/{name}/{popu}",method=RequestMethod.POST,headers="Accept=application/json")
    public List<Country> addCountry(@PathVariable String name , @PathVariable String popu){
        Country country = new Country();
        country.setCountryName(name);
        country.setPopulation(popu);

        try {
            countryService.addCountry(country);
            return countryService.getAllCountries();
        } catch (CountryException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/countries/delete/{id}",method=RequestMethod.DELETE,headers="Accept=application/json")
    public List<Country> deleteCountry(@PathVariable String id){
        try {
            countryService.delete(id);
            return countryService.getAllCountries();
        } catch (CountryException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can _you_ tell us what is wrong!? Any console error?

Comment: Actually I am trying to run my first angularjs application with spring. I am a beginner so i dont have much knowledge of it and after running the .html page the javascript written is not working @MatthewCawley

Comment: try to remove the alert() from the configuration object in your three $http services, so that they look like $http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'}).success ...

Comment: yes it worked. thank you @darron614 and one more thing can you tell me is there any other error in remove functionin html?
Because the data after clicking on the button is passing '0' value to index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the alert() from the configuration object in your three $http services, so that they look like 
`$http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'}).success ...`
Also try and change the remove function call from:

```
<td><button ng-click="remove{$index}">Remove</button></td>
```

to:

```
<td><button ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</button></td>
```

Comment: Thechanges worked. thank you
can you please tell me how to validate fields in the given html form.
Validations are like country name should be required and population should be numerical @darron614